# jQuery cannot compare offset result with int/string

Tags: jquery

So for my portfolio which is currently under development I need to work with the offset coords of a specific div. The div which I am getting the offset of has got position fixed and starts with top:150px.

So basically I want to console.log ayy when the offset is between 150 and 550.
The problem is it always returns ayy even though it surpasses 550.
I tried this without parseInt and with but both ways don't work.

This is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentOffset = $('#offset').offset().top;
    currentOffset = parseInt(currentOffset);
    console.log(currentOffset);
    if(($(currentOffset) >= '150') && ($(currentOffset <= '550'))) {
        console.log('ayy');
    }
    else {
        console.log('nay');
    }
});
```

This is what my console logs
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHOXi.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `150` and `550`. Also `offset().top` returns an int so `parseInt()` is redundant

Comment: No need to convert to `int`,  `if($('#offset').offset().top > 150 && $('#offset').offset().top < 550)`

Comment: Tried that, without the quotes is always returns nay, oved it anyway thanks

Comment: Satpal your answer worked, thank you. Could you explain why my code didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offset().top` returns an int so `parseInt()` is redundant and you are creating jQuery object when you are using `$(currentOffset)` just use it directly `currentOffset`.

*Use*

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentOffset = $('#offset').offset().top; 
    if (currentOffset >= 150 && currentOffset <= 550) {
        console.log('ayy');
    } else {
        console.log('nay');
    }
});
```

Note: You are not using `()` properly.

Comment: Thank you Satpal, this worked. This will help me in the long run as well. It seems I cannot mark your answer as the answer yet. Is there some time limit regarding this? *Yes, i need to wait 6 min, again, thank you*